# Por que o R tem várias pastas para as Bibliotecas?

Tags: r, biblioteca

Atualizei a versão do R para a 4.0 e estou tendo problemas com algumas bibliotecas.

Tentando arrumar isso, encontrei o comando `.libPaths()`

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/home/usuario/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0" "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"                    
[3] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"                           "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

Fiquei curioso, por que o R tem quatro pastas para as bibliotecas?
Além das pastas de versões (....linux-gnu-library/3.6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Nota prévia: Todas as traduções [DeepL Translate](https://www.deepl.com/translator) e [Google Translate](https://translate.google.pt/), editas por mim.*

A explicação pode ser encontrada no próprio R mas antes veja esta resposta do usuário [Dirk Eddelbuettel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38417179/8245406) datada de 17 de Julho de 2016 a uma pergunta no StackOverflow em Inglês, ênfase minha.

> See `help(Startup)` for the full and detailed treatment. **On Debian and
> Ubuntu we have been setting these three directories as the default for
> well over a decade.** As it is set via `R_LIBS_SITE` here, this is the
> variable you need to alter here. In general, you need to override the
> variable holding the value and you may not know *ex ante* which one
> that is.

Em Português, ênfase minha.

> Ver `help(Startup)` para o tratamento completo e detalhado. **Em Debian
> e Ubuntu temos vindo a definir estes três directórios como o padrão há
> mais de uma década.** Como é definido através de `R_LIBS_SITE`, é esta a
> variável que precisa de alterar. Em geral, é necessário anular a
> variável que detém o valor e pode não saber *ex ante* qual delas é que
> é.

Na verdade, no ficheiro `/etc/R/Renviron`, quase no fim, podemos ver onde estes diretórios estão definidos. Repare nas datas das edições e, sobretudo, no comentário à primeira.

```
# edd Apr 2003  Allow local install in /usr/local, also add a directory for
#               Debian packaged CRAN packages, and finally the default dir 
# edd Jul 2007  Now use R_LIBS_SITE, not R_LIBS
R_LIBS_SITE=${R_LIBS_SITE-'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library:/usr/lib/R/site-library:/usr/lib/R/library'}
```

O comentário à primeira linha acima pode ser dividido em três, cada parte com a razão para incluir cada um dos três diretórios.

1. Allow local install in `/usr/local`;
2. add a directory for Debian packaged CRAN packages;
3. the default dir.

Em Português.

1. Permitir instalação local em `/usr/local`;
2. adicionar um diretório para pacotes CRAN preparados para Debian;
3. o diretório padrão.

**Versão do R e sistema operacional.**

```
rui@rui:~$ R -q -e 'sessionInfo()'
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.9.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=pt_PT.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=pt_PT.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=pt_PT.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=pt_PT.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=pt_PT.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=pt_PT.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=pt_PT.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.2
> 
>
```

Comment: Excelente! Obrigado!